# Is there a Martin Gardner's article archive available online?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request

Martin Gardener was a great recreational mathematics expert and his column "Mathematical Games" is an all time hit. But is there any archive available online consisting of his articles (preferably in PDF format)? I searched online but I got only one or two articles in PDF format.

Comment: I got a lot more by typing "martin gardner pdf" into Google. See Gardner's home site for a more structured experience http://martin-gardner.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About 20 of Martin Gardner's books are available.  In print, in iBooks, in Kindle, and probably other sources.  Is there some reason you cannot pay for them?

**added**
All the "Mathematical Games" columns from Scientific American: you can get them on one [CD](http://www.maa.org/press/books/martin-gardner-s-mathematical-games-the-entire-collection-of-his-scientific-american-columns-on-one)  ...about $51 from Amazon.com, cheaper from the MAA if you are a member.

Comment: Are those books contains every article he wrote for Scientific American?

Comment: Yes.  He published volumes once a year with the 12 columns for that year.  But if you want all the Sci. Am. columns, you can get them on CD.  Answer edited to link to it.

Comment: Hmmm thanks for the link but in India $51 is a lot of money. Anyways I have found the cd link in library genesis though.

Answer (score 1):

Not strictly an archive, but some related materials to Martin Gardner and his history can be found at https://www.gathering4gardner.org/

Answer (score -1):

Try here: https://z-lib.org/

In this site, just by typing 'Martin Gardner', you'll find almost all the books and papers written by Gardner, in particular, all the 'Mathematical Games' articles published in 'Scientific American'.